# Initial conditions that converge to an unstable equilibrium

Tags: recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems, control-theory, ergodic-theory

Consider the discrete-time dynamical system
\begin{align}
x_{k+1}=T(x_k),
\end{align}
where $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $x_k\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $x_0$ is the initial condition, and $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is a diffeomorphism on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Assume $x_{\rm u}$ is an unstable equilibrium. I think that it's well-known that the set of initial conditions which converge to $x_{\rm u}$ is a set of Lebesgue measure zero. I can't find the proof, but I believe that I can prove it using the center manifold theorem.

1) Is that right?

2) How about the case of uncountable number of unstable equilibria? I mean assuming that the set $\mathcal{U}\triangleq\{x_{\rm u}\in\mathbb{R}^n:x_{\rm u} {\rm ~is~ an~ unstable~ equilibrium~ of~ the~ system}\}$ is uncountable with Lebesgue measure zero, is that true that the set of initial conditions which converge to $\mathcal{U}$ is a set of Lebesegue measure zero?

Any hint, counterexample, proof, or reference? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any proof but let me try to give intuition for linear systems, or linearization around the equilibrium if you wish. Let the linearized model is $x_{k+1} = A x_k$. If $Au_i = \lambda_i u_i$, then $x_k = \lambda_i^k u_i$ is a solution. If $|\lambda_i| < 1$, then the system converges to the equilibrium for $x_0 = u_i$. Since this system is unstable $A$ has at least one eigenvalue such that $|\lambda| > 1$. This means the set of initial conditions which converge to the equilibrium are at most $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace spanned by the stable eigenvectors of $A$ and I think this subspace has Lebesgue measure of $0$ inside $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Roughly speaking, that's the right idea. Note that being unstable does not mean necessarily that $A$ has an unstable eigenvalue, so one needs to use center manifold (or center eigenspace of $A$). The point is that I don't know how this kind of argument will work for uncountable number of equilibria.

Answer (score 4):

Take ODE $\dot x=x^2$. Then $\hat{x}=0$ is unstable, and at the same time it attracts any point from $(-\infty,0)$.

If you are unhappy with this example, take a system in polar coordinates
$$
\dot r=r(1-r),\\
\dot \theta=\sin^2(\theta/2)+(r-1)^2
$$
The equilibrium $(1,0)$ is unstable, however it attracts orbits starting at *any* point in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Thanks, but my question is about the discrete-time systems. The stability properties of continuous-time system is quite different form this point of view and I am aware that my conjectures clearly don't hold in continuous-time.

Comment: Also note that $T$ is supposed to be a diffeomorphism.

Comment: Take an ODE $\dot x=f(x)$. Consider its flow $x(t)=\phi^tx(0)$. Consider a 1-shift map $\phi^1$. Then you will get a discrete diffeomorphism whose orbits will lay exactly on the orbits of the original ODE system.

Comment: @Mohkam7 Did you get anything from the answer?

Comment: Actually no. If you think you can get anything from a discretization of an ODE, please  write it more carefully. BTW,  your examples are not diffeomorphism. I don't know how they become diffeomorphism after discretization.

Comment: @Mohkam7 This is not discretezation. This is an elementary construction of a discrete system that has exactly the same orbits. By the properties of ODE, htese are diffeomorphisms.

Comment: @Mohkam7 If you accepted an incorrect answer, why did you bother to ask this question at all?